# How does Prometheus calculate the average of the past 24 hours?

Tags: prometheus, promql

The 'vip_front_onload_duration[24h] specified interval' has 3 points, and I want to calculate the average of  these 3 points' sum.

avg_over_time(vip_front_onload_duration{pageid=~"pay.xxx.com/pay.html"}[24h])

result is

```sh
{instance="xxx:7002",job="vip_monitor",pageid="pay.xxx.com/pay.html",quantile="0.5"}    2524.586342592599
{instance="xxx:7002",job="vip_monitor",pageid="pay.xxx.com/pay.html",quantile="0.9"}    11592.012384259262
{instance="xxx:7002",job="vip_monitor",pageid="pay.xxx.com/pay.html",quantile="0.99"}   77310.7171296294
```

This expression, Avg_over_time(vip_front_onload_duration{pageid=~"pay.xxx.com/pay.html"}[24h]), calculate respectively the average of 'quantine='0.5|0.9|0.99'' and I want to acquire the average of those three indicators' sum.